# can we use setNodeValue method to set the node value for rest services as we do for soap services in SoapUI tool?

Tags: rest, groovy, soapui, web-api-testing

can we use setNodeValue method to set the node value for rest services as we do for soap services in the SoapUI tool?

ex-

XMLHolder.**setNodeValue**("//typ:name", name)

XMLHolder.**setNodeValue**("//typ:id", id)

XMLHolder.**setNodeValue**("//typ:Department", dept)

XMLHolder.**setNodeValue**("//typ:age", age)

Comment: If my answer helped can you mark it as accepted ?

Answer (score 1):

REST accommodates XML as well as JSON, which one do you ask for ? If you use XML you can use the same approach and if its for a JSON then follow the below

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

// Define Request
def request = '{ "name":"John", "country":"India", "car":"Honda" }'

// Parse The Request
def jsonReq = new JsonSlurper().parseText(request);

// Set Values
jsonReq.name = "Wilfred"
jsonReq.country = "India"
jsonReq.car = "Honda"

// Parse JSON to string
def jsonReqAsString = JsonOutput.toJson(jsonReq)

// Print or You can do anything
log.info (jsonReqAsString)
```